# Laravel vue: I can't get the object related to the relationship betwenn models

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I've created a simple comment system. Everything's working fine. Now I had to create the same approach with Vue.js. Everything works well with Vue.j too. The only problem is that I can't show the answers related to the comment using the relationship.
I show first the relationship code, then the PHP loop and finally the loop code with Vue.js

```
//USER MODEL
public function comments()
{
return $this->hasMany(Comment::class,'user_id');
}

//COMMENT MODEL
public function video()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Video::class);
}


public function user()
{
return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}


public function replies()
{
return $this->hasMany(CommentReply::class,'comment_id');
}


 //CommentReply model
 public function comment()
 {
  return $this->belongsTo(Comment::class);
}
```

**This is the loop**

```
         @foreach( $video->comments as $comment )
        <li id="li-comment-5">
            <article class="comment even thread-odd thread-alt depth-1 clr" id="comment-5"> 

                    <header class="comment-meta"> <strong class="fn"> {{ $comment->user->name }} 
          </strong> <span class="comment-date">July 4, 2017 7:25 am </span></header>
                    <div class="comment-content entry clr">
                        <p>{{ $comment-body}}</p>
                    </div>

                    <h5>Reply</h5>


                    @foreach($comment->replies as $reply)

                         $reply->body
                      @enddoreach

                </div>
            </article>
        </li>
            @endforeach
```

**Loop with Vue**

```
<ol class="commentlist" v-if="comments.length > 0">
 <li id="li-comment-4" v-for="comment in comments">
  //...loop works fine

  //Reply section
 </li<ul class="children">
 <li id="li-comment-6" v-for="reply in comment.replies">
   //comment.replies does not work
  </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  </ol>
```

As you can see in the code below comment.replies does not return the object I am waiting for.
How can you get the same result with vue?

Comment: // user model 
public function comments()
{
return $this->hasMany(Comment::class,'user_id')->with('replies');
}

Comment: Hi, I put the relationship: return $this->hasMany(Comment::class,'user_id')->with('replies'); But It does not show the replies...

Comment: dd($video);    to take a look at the data before you pass it to VUE. dd in the controller before it's passed to blade. Blade will make new db queries with using relationship/eloquent snytax, however VUE will not. So any data you need either needs to be passed complete in a prop , or fetched via api.